Projective space as Grassmannian
I want to understand how (or rather, why) the schemes representing the functors of $n-1$-dimensional projective space and the Grassmannian of lines are equivalent. More concretely, for an integer $n > 1$, the functors in question are
$$\Bbb P^{n-1} : (\text{Sch})^\text{opp} \to (\text{Set}), \quad S \mapsto \{ (\mathcal L, \phi) \mid \phi: \mathcal O_S^n \to \mathcal L \}/\sim,$$
where $\mathcal L$ is a line bundle and $\phi$ is a surjection. The Grassmannian $\text{Gr}_{n,1}$ is defined as the functor with same source and target, sending a scheme $S$ to the set
$$\text{Gr}_{n,1}(S) = \{U \subset \mathcal O_S^n \mid \mathcal O_S^n/U \text{ is locally free of rank } n-1\}.$$
It is well known that both functors are representable, and the representing objects are isomorphic. One construction of an isomorphism is given, for example, in Chapter 8 of the book by Görtz-Wedhorn. However, the isomorphism given there is of scheme-theoretic nature, and I don't see what the corresponding morphism of sheaves is.
My question is: Given a section of the Grassmannian, given by a subsheaf, how do we construct the corresponding equivalence class of surjections onto a line bundle? Conversely, given an equivalence class of surjections onto a line bundle, how do we construct the submodule of $\mathcal O_S^n$?


Given a section of the Grassmannian, given by a subsheaf, how do we construct the corresponding equivalence class of surjections onto a line bundle?

You dualize the sequence $0\to U\to \mathcal O_S^n \to \mathcal O_S^n/U\to 0$ to obtain the line bundle $\mathcal L = U^\vee$.

Conversely, given an equivalence class of surjections onto a line bundle, how do we construct the submodule of $\mathcal O_S^n$.?

Take $U$ to be dual to $\mathcal L$.
